# DPM 2010 Agent Problem

Tags: sql-server-2008, scdpm, agent

We have a problem with our DPM 2010.My problem is ;
I uninstalled old DPM agent on SQL Server Server,then I installed new DPM Agent,But,that's gives me error.
Also,I installed as manuel,again it is gives the error.
Here is my error message.

```
The protection agent operation failed because it could not access the  protection        
agent  on makinaadi.domain.com.tr. makinaadi.domain.com.tr may be  running DPM, 
or the DPM protection agent may have been installed by another DPM server. (ID 302 Details: )
```

[My Error Message](http://i1102.hizliresim.com/2011/2/3/1196.jpg)

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a DPM agent on a 2k8R2 DC. You can remove the agent from within the server through Programs/Features in the control panel. Then remove the agent from within the DPM Console and disable the firewall on the SQL Server, and finally do regular install of the agent from within the DPM console. That's the process that worked for me.